# How can I define an enum that returns a String that satisfies the "needs" of a String WITHOUT rawvalue?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I am trying to learn develop and implement Swift 5.x enum(s) in my own coding projects. And I am not quite getting the concept of when/how the case and switch statements are used.

In this case I have this **working** line of code:

```swift
vc.addAttachmentData(myPDFFile! as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: myFileNameToAttach)
```

I am trying to write (and learn) **Swift 5 enum that will let me write this WITHOUT needed to add `.rawvalue`**:

```swift
vc.addAttachmentData(myPDFFile! as Data, mimeType: Attach.pdf, fileName: myFileNameToAttach)
```

This is what I have got that is *NOT* generating any errors and is also **NOT working**:

```swift
enum Attach: String {
    case jpg = "image/jpeg"
    case png = "image/png"
    case doc = "application/msword"
    case ppt = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
    case html = "text/html"
    case pdf = "application/pdf"

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        switch rawValue.lowercased() {
            case "jpg": self = .jpg
            case "png": self = .png
            case "doc": self = .doc
            case "ppt": self = .ppt
            case "html": self = .html
            case "pdf": self = .pdf
            default: return nil
        }
    }
}

var mydummy = Attach.pdf    //
print(type(of: mydummy))    // Attach
print(mydummy)              // pdf
```

Comment: Why use enum cases at all? Why not just have `static let pdf = "application/pdf"` in `Attach`?

Answer (score 0):

I think `rawValue` suits the case. If you prefer writing `Attach.pdf`, you can create a struct called `Attach`, and declare `pdf` as its property.

```swift
struct Attach {
  let pdf = "application/pdf"
  //...
}
```

Comment: Much easier is to simply import UniformTypeIdemtifiers

Comment: Agreed.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/system_declared_uniform_type_identifiers